# Is there an audit on IPS while reviewing?

Tags: discussion

I just noticed the following:

> Hat earned - **peacekeeper**
>
> Successfully complete 20 reviews without failing an audit.

What's weird is that, since the winterbash started, I made more (much much more) than 20 reviews. I (think I usually) have no problem with reviewing the VTC, LQP and so on... And when in doubt, I just skip. Mainly, I have very few "looks OK" clicks because there's no need for that, no triage, and very low spam. On other stacks, this can lead to fail an audit.

So, I don't see how an audit could be done here on IPS, but that's another problem. :)

**On IPS, is there an audit (are there tests?) you can fail/succeed while reviewing like on other stacks or is it just a generic hat for all stacks?**

Comment: IPS [doesn't have review audits enabled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157172/369802). That leaves the question of what is a successful audit, that I don't really know.

Comment: Thought it could have been done without warning though ;)

Answer (score 1):

IPS does not have a test on audits, so everything is considered successful audit, and also,

You have to have 20 reviews on a specific queue, that's why it took so long to get it.

So actually IPS is pretty easy for you to get Peacekeeper hat, not saying the audit tests are hard :-)

Comment: You might want to change your phrasing: "actually IPS is pretty easy for you to get Peacekeeper hat" as some people might read it as you undermining the work of your reviewers (a good IPS review takes time and isn't easy to do for edge case, which we have a lot of)

Comment: @Noon I'm sure that's not the intent. It's just easier to complete 20 reviews without failing an audit if there's no audits on IPS ;-)

Comment: @Tinkeringbell I'm sure it's not the intent as well but that's how I read it before mealtime and it took me a full belly to read it differently. Since I don't want other people to interpret this the wrong way as well, I'm suggesting U9-Forward to edit to clarify/re-phrase.

Comment: @tinkeringbell : yup, that's the proper phrasing I guess